# File assocations inconsistent behaviour with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python, file-association, command-line-arguments

After updating Python, my file associations somehow got messed up and I have been trying to get them to behave.  Here's my test program PyArgs.py:

```
import sys, os 
print ("Arguments count  : " + str (len (sys.argv)))
print ("Arguments        : " + str (sys.argv))
print ("Python version   : " + sys.version) ;
print ("Python executable: " + sys.executable) ;
print ("Script path      : " + os.path.realpath(__file__))
exit
```

and there is a console dump that illustrates my problem:

```
C:\TOOLS>"C:\Users\Raymond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" pyargs.py 1 2 3
Arguments count  : 4
Arguments        : ['pyargs.py', '1', '2', '3']
Python version   : 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python executable: C:\Users\Raymond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Script path      : C:\TOOLS\pyargs.py

C:\TOOLS>pyargs.py 1 2 3
Arguments count  : 1                                                     <=========================== ??
Arguments        : ['C:\\TOOLS\\pyargs.py']                              <=========================== ??
Python version   : 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python executable: C:\Users\Raymond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Script path      : C:\TOOLS\pyargs.py

C:\TOOLS>assoc .py
.py=Python.File

C:\TOOLS>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Users\Raymond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" "%L" %*
```

So if I invoke the script explicitly with the path to `python.exe`, the script sees the parameters, but if I invoke it via the `.py` file association it doesn't.  What am I missing?

I have tagged the question as `python` but  I'm not convinced that is anything to do with python, just my incomplete configuration of the file associations.

If I go to the file association settings I see:

[image]

The second `Python` icon looks like it might be associated with command-line operation.  Anyway, I changed the `.py` file association to that icon and the behaviour hasn't changed.

Comment: Click on Start, Settings, Apps, Default Apps, then scroll down the right select and select Default Apps by File Type and associate .py with Python. That should work

Comment: Hi John.  Please see my edits to the question.

Comment: I am not sure why this has occurred. Try running the two basic Windows Repairs.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:  (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  and then (2) sfc /scannow  . Restart when done and check file associations again.